# Mac In app purchase - Receipt contains more than 1 consumable item at the same time

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase

I'n writing an example about in app purchase for Mac. At the first time, after purchase item 1, I receive this JSON (follow this instruction [Online receipt validation for in app purchases for MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598047/online-receipt-validation-for-in-app-purchases-for-mac)):

```
{

environment = Sandbox;

receipt =     {

    "adam_id" = 0;

    "app_item_id" = 0;

    "application_version" = "1.0";

    "bundle_id" = "com.mac.OSXReceipt";

    "download_id" = 0;

    "in_app" =         (
            {

            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:28 Etc/GMT";

            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1416527008000;

            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:28 America/Los_Angeles";

            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000132520356;

            "product_id" = "com.mac.OSXReceipt.1";

            "purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:28 Etc/GMT";

            "purchase_date_ms" = 1416527008000;

            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:28 America/Los_Angeles";

            quantity = 1;

            "transaction_id" = 1000000132520356;

        }

    );

    "original_application_version" = "1.0";

    "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";

    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;

    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";

    "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;

    "request_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:30 Etc/GMT";

    "request_date_ms" = 1416527010147;

    "request_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:30 America/Los_Angeles";

    "version_external_identifier" = 0;

};

status = 0;
```

And when I purchase the item 2, I receive this JSON:

```
{

environment = Sandbox;

receipt =     {

    "adam_id" = 0;

    "app_item_id" = 0;

    "application_version" = "1.0";

    "bundle_id" = "com.mac.OSXReceipt";

    "download_id" = 0;

    "in_app" =         (
            {

            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:28 Etc/GMT";

            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1416527008000;

            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:28 America/Los_Angeles";

            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000132520356;

            "product_id" = "com.mac.OSXReceipt.1";

            "purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:28 Etc/GMT";

            "purchase_date_ms" = 1416527008000;

            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:28 America/Los_Angeles";

            quantity = 1;

            "transaction_id" = 1000000132520356;

        },
         {

            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:44:25 Etc/GMT";

            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1416527065000;

            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:44:25 America/Los_Angeles";

            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000132520389;

            "product_id" = "com.mac.OSXReceipt.2";

            "purchase_date" = "2014-11-20 23:44:25 Etc/GMT";

            "purchase_date_ms" = 1416527065000;

            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:44:25 America/Los_Angeles";

            quantity = 1;

            "transaction_id" = 1000000132520389;

        }

    );

    "original_application_version" = "1.0";

    "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";

    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;

    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";

    "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;

    "request_date" = "2014-11-20 23:43:30 Etc/GMT";

    "request_date_ms" = 1416527010147;

    "request_date_pst" = "2014-11-20 15:43:30 America/Los_Angeles";

    "version_external_identifier" = 0;

};

status = 0;
```

And if I continue purchase other item, it will be added in this list too. I checked all items are consumable item, and I called finish transaction in my project too. So my question is why in the receipt contain more than 1 consumable item at the same time and how to finish (remove) the old items in this list. Thanks.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this looking for an answer for my next question, but the answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20474299).

Basically this is because since the introduction of iOS7 not a single receipt is returned but all receipts for this user within the app are returned. I presume this has to do something with support for subscriptions.